# Get Max number in column based on 2 Lookups

Tags: excel-formula

I need a formula to:

1. Lookup in its own column for the largest #
2. only if conditions are met in column 1 and 2
3. Add 1 to the found number and insert it into the cell

In other words, I want to "filter" my list for rows that have X in column 1 and Y in column 2
and then get the largest number from column 3 within these rows.

Then add 1 to that number.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Post some sample data, and what you want to get for a result. Then people might be able to help you.

Comment: Also, since this looks like an Excel quetion, [su] might be a better place to ask. Again, don't forget my earlier suggestion when you post there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its a "give me the code" question. You should probably [Take the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a array formula:

```
{=MAX(IF(($A$1:$A$1000="x")*($B$1:$B$1000="y"),$C$1:$C$1000))+1}
```

Input:

```
=MAX(IF(($A$1:$A$1000="x")*($B$1:$B$1000="y"),$C$1:$C$1000))+1
```

and then [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to create a array formula.
Then should there be automatically the curly brackets around the formula.

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your response, but this doesnt seem to work.
I am getting an error message in the formula

But, one more thing I would like to mention: if the largest # is < 100 then instead of adding 1, add 101

Thanks

Comment: Which is the error you get? You will get a "not available" error, if the sizes of the ranges within the if condition `($A$1:$A$1000="x")*($B$1:$B$1000="y")` is not equal. For ex. `IF(($A$1:$A$1000="x")*($B$1:$B$100="y"),..)` will throw this error.

Comment: Hi Axel. Thanks for your response. I dont remember what the error was - it wasnt "Not available" though. In the end, I left this method because I realized I was running into a different problem which was circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

Standard (non-array) equivalent for MAXIF() functionality would look like:

```
=MAX(INDEX(C2:C999*(A2:A999="X")*(B2:B999="Y"),,))+1
```

With your added condition for adding 100 to numbers less than 100 then,

```
=MAX(INDEX((C2:C999+(C2:C999<100)*100)*(A2:A999="X")*(B2:B999="Y"),,))+1
```

For versions of Excel that are 2010 and higher, the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can use the conditional criteria to throw errors then ignore the errors when processing the [MAX function](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/max-function-f7bec1eb-9c66-489a-9166-51d2c9d19333).

[image: MAXIF with AGGREAGATE]

The standard formulas for E5:E6 are,

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, $C$2:$C$99/(($A$2:$A$99="X")*($B$2:$B$99="Y")), 1)
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, ($C$2:$C$99+($C$2:$C$99<100)*100)/(($A$2:$A$99="X")*($B$2:$B$99="Y")), 1)
```

In fact, AGGREGATE is using its [LARGE sub-function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) with *1* as the *k* parameter. Locating the second, third, etc. largest values which meet the criteria is a simple matter of sequencing the *k* parameter. This can be done with `ROW(1:1)` then filling the formula down.

¹<sub>[AGGREGATE¹](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced in Excel 2010. It is not available in previous versions.</sub>